# git how to do diff outside of working tree

Tags: git

I'm working on a branch `foo` that maybe looks like:

```
A --> B --> C --> D
^                 ^
master            foo
```

Meanwhile, a colleague pushes a branch `bar` and asks for a code review:

```
              origin/bar
              v
  E --> G --> G
 /
A --> B --> C --> D
^                 ^
master            foo
```

Is there a way for me to check out the diff between `master` and `origin/bar` without having to first `git checkout bar`? As is, regardless if I do:

```
git diff A bar
git diff A origin/bar
```

I get:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'bar': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/bar': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Comment: Did you remember to `git fetch` first? It looks like, although your colleague pushed his updates to a central repo, you haven't yet downloaded those changes into your working repo...

Comment: I did `git fetch origin bar`, but while that gave me a `* branch bar -> FETCH_HEAD`, it didn't seem to create the branch. Not until I did `git checkout master; git pull --rebase;` was I able to diff against the branch.

Comment: Don't do `git fetch origin bar`, just do `git fetch origin`.  The four-word version means "call up `origin`, obtain everything needed for its branch `bar`, and save that in my repo under the name `FETCH_HEAD`" ... but you want to save it under the name `origin/bar`.  The three-word version means "call up `origin`, obtain everything they have I don't, and file them away under `origin/` as appropriate".  This potentially fetches more stuff now, but presumably you want it all eventually, and you don't want everything stuffed into the special `FETCH_HEAD` file as it can get lost on the next fetch.

Comment: @torek Yep that works. Want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, the colleague has published the changes at a particular remote repository: in this case, the centralized server, which your git has under the name `origin`.  You need to obtain these changes.

If you run `git fetch origin`, your git will call up the remote and bring over all available branches, storing them in `origin/name`.  You only *need* `origin/bar` to show up in your own repository at the moment, but if you specifically *ask* for *just* `bar`, with `git fetch origin bar`, this four-argument form of `fetch` stores the fetched result under the name `FETCH_HEAD`.

The easy way to handle this is to run `git fetch origin`, without the fourth argument.  In fact, you can usually leave off `origin` as well; see below.  While this brings over *everything* new, you probably eventually want all of that anyway, and it's a lot easier to let the computer do the work.

Once you've done that, you can simply name the other branch: `git diff A origin/bar`, just as you attempted.

(If you do bring over just their `bar`, and name it `FETCH_HEAD`, it's possible that you'll do something else that overwrites `FETCH_HEAD`, which makes the objects you brought over the first time eligible to be garbage-collected.  If they get garbage-collected, a later fetch will just have to bring them over again, so you might as well use the easy way to bring over everything once.  Under some special circumstances, though, you might want to use the `FETCH_HEAD` method.  For instance, if you're temporarily on a very slow or expensive service, it may be worth it to limit what you bring over.  In this case, just use the name `FETCH_HEAD` instead of `origin/bar`—or you can even use the raw SHA-1 IDs.)

---

When can you leave off `origin` entirely?  The answer is in the [`git fetch` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), using git's traditional opaque verbiage:

> When no remote is specified, by default the `origin` remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch.

What that means is that git first checks to see what the current branch is.  That's the branch prefixed with a `*` in `git branch` output, although the shorter way to find out is to use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.  It's possible that there is no current branch—that you are in "detached HEAD" mode—in which case `fetch` falls back on the default.

If you are on a branch, though, the next step is to see whether there's a configured upstream.  That's the branch shown in square brackets in `git branch -vv` output:

```
foo    222d4dd [bobs-computer/foo] some commit or another
master d157b48 [origin/master] another commit message
testbr d34b333 third commit message
```

Here `foo` has `bobs-computer/foo` as its upstream, `master` has `origin/master` as its upstream, and `testbr` has *no* upstream.

If there *is* an upstream, git will fetch from whatever remote it is: `bobs-computer` in the case of `foo`, `origin` in the case of `master`.  If there's no upstream, `fetch` falls back on `origin`, just as with the detached-HEAD no-branch case.

(To configure an upstream, use `git branch --set-upstream-to=...`; but by default when you check out a tracking branch, it's automatically configured for you.  The actual configuration is saved in your git config file and is in two parts: `branch.name.remote` and `branch.name.merge`.  Unsurprisingly, the first gives the name of the remote, and is really all `fetch` needs.  The second part gives the name of the branch *as stored on the remote*, i.e., without the branch renaming that `fetch` does so that `origin/master` is in fact named `origin/master` in your own repository.)

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff fingerprinterD fingerprintG
```